# custom converter in XStream

Tags: converters, xstream

I am using XStream to serialize my Objects to XML format. The formatted xml that I get is as below: node1, node2, node 3 are attributes of pojo,DetailDollars

I have requirement where in I have to calucluate a percentage, for example 100/ 25 and add the new node to the existing  ones. So, the final output should be :

```
<DetailDollars>
    <node1>100 </node1> 
    <node2>25</node2> 
    <node3>10</node3> 
</DetailDollars>
```

I wrote a custom converter and registered to my xstream object.

```
public void marshal(..){
         writer.startNode("node4");         
         writer.setValue(getNode1()/ getnode2() );
         writer.endNode();
}
```

But, the xml stream I get has only the new node:

```
<DetailDollars> 
    <node4>4</node4>
</DetailDollars>
```

I am not sure which xstream api would get me the desired format. could you please help me with this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the converter you need:

```
public class DetailDollarsConverter extends ReflectionConverter {

public DetailDollarsConverter(Mapper mapper,
        ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider) {
    super(mapper, reflectionProvider);
}

@Override
public void marshal(Object obj, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
        MarshallingContext context) {
    super.marshal(obj,writer,context);

    DetailDollars dl = (DetailDollars) obj;

    writer.startNode("node4");
    writer.setValue(Double.toString(dl.getNode1() / dl.getNode2()));
    writer.endNode();
}

@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
        UnmarshallingContext context) {
    return super.unmarshal(reader,context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.equals(DetailDollars.class);
}
```

}