# XStream custom converter that can generate flat XML structure from List?

Tags: java, xstream

I'm using XStream and have a class with a field like the following:

```
private Map<String, String> data;
```

I want to generate XML output like this:

```
<key1>test data</key1>
<key2>test data</key2>
<key3>test data</key3>
```

So I want the map key to be the element. The mapvalue to be the XML value and I don't want the XML wrapped in an element such as `<data></data>`. Can anyone point to sample code that does this, or something similar?

**UPDATE**

This just a snippet, there is a root element.

**UPDATE 2**

The custom converter code I posted below almost works.  I get a flat structure, but I need to remove the outer element.  Any idea on that?

```
//this is the result need to remove <data>
<data>
    <key1>test data</key1>
    <key2>test data</key2>
    <key3>test data</key3>
</data>
```

This is the code

```
public class MapToFlatConverter implements Converter{
   public MapToFlatConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return Map.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) source;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            writer.startNode(entry.getKey());
            writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        //not needed at this time

        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Valid XML must not have multiple root elements.

Comment: this is just a snippet.  There is a root element.  I just want the list elements to appear flat.

Comment: what is with the close votes?  This seems like a question that SO was created for.

Comment: Maybe you could show us some code, the current output and a more complete expected output. (For the record: I did not vote to close this, just trying to help).

Comment: How would you unmarshal it without the containing element?

Comment: In my case I don't need to unmarshal it.  I'm serializing some Java objects to XML & sending it to an external system.  The external system doesn't return any XML that I need to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working.  The following SO post is what I ultimately did:  [custom converter in XStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456909/custom-converter-in-xstream).  I needed to extend from the ReflectionConverter:

This next post helped also, though when I tried this approach the context.convertAnother() method did not seem to work.  So I switched to the method in the 1st post.

[Xstream Implicit Map As Attributes to Root Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608007/xstream-implicit-map-as-attributes-to-root-element)